# How to run spring boot application both as a web application as well as a command line application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, command-line-arguments

Currently, I am trying to use the `CommandLineRunner` along with the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` to run a spring boot application both as a web application by default and as a standalone command line application on demand (via command line parameters of some sort). I am struggling figuring out how to solely run this as a console application when program arguments are supplied. Please any suggestions would help.

- [Main class - SpringApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32NsC.png)
- [CommandLineRunner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaBqJ.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am solving exactly same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Artegon you can refer to my solution below.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same requirement. This is how I was able to achieve it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        if (args.length == 0) { // This can be any condition you want
            app.web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET);
        } else {
            app.web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        }
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

And this is a console application runner.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
public class ConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("************************** CONSOLE APP *********************************");
    }
}
```

When you build your `bootJar`, you can run application as Web app using
`java -jar app.jar` and as a command line app using `java -jar app.jar anything #based on the condition you specified`.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

A better way to achieve this is changing Application.java as following and keeping ConsoleApplication.java as shown above.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and then running your `bootJar` with `java -jar -Dspring.main.web-application-type=NONE app.jar` will run the application as console application. And not passing any `spring.main.web-application-type` will run as a web application.

Comment: Thanks, the above answer was not garbage, nor was it necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 6):

The `CommandLineRunner` interface provides a useful way of picking up command line arguments once the application has started, but it won’t help change the nature of the application. As you’ve probably discovered, the application will probably not exit since it thinks it needs to handle incoming web requests.

The approach you’ve taken in your main method looks sensible to me. You need to tell Spring Boot that it isn’t a web application, and therefor shouldn’t hang around listening for incoming requests once it’s been started.

I’d do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AutoDbServiceApplication.class);
    application.setWeb(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(args);
    application.run(args);
}
```

That should start the application in the correct mode. Then you can use a `CommandLineRunner` bean in the same way as you currently do. You might also want to look at `ApplicationRunner` which has a slightly better API:

```
@Component
public class AutoDbApplicationRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(args.getSourceArgs)) {
            return; // Regular web application
        }
        // Do something with the args.
        if (args.containsOption(“foo”)) {
            // …
        }
    }

}
```

If you really don’t want the `AutoDbApplicationRunner` bean to even be created you could look at setting a profile in the main method that you could use later (see `SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles`).

Comment: Thanks Phil Webb !

Comment: Is this still the best way to include some CLI commands in a spring boot web app? If I use ApplicationRunner, is it possible to prevent the web app from starting after returning from “run” and a CLI command was run?

Comment: I tried this way but i get some errors in other parts of my application, like `Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean named 'A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.' that could not be found.`